# Selenium NoSuchMethodError even though the method exists

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have Selenium version 4.4, java 11 and use the following line:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Which yields and error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, java.time.Duration)'
    at com.web.Power.Web.Webproject.<init>(Webproject.java:82)
```

I import Duration using `import java.time.Duration;`.

***What could be the issue here?***

Comment: This usually indicates that you’re using a different version of a library at runtime than the version the code was compiled with. Check how your dependencies are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in replacement of wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```